# How to use SVM classifier with keras CNN model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, svm

I am working on predicting seizure epilepsy using CNN. I have 2 classes in my dataset. I want to use CNN model as a feature extractor, then I want to use SVM as a classifier. I don't know how to do this with my model.

I am using `mode.fit_generator` in my model and I don't have x and y because I use generator for my data. How can I use the traditional SVM for my model?

**My model**

```
 input_shape=(33,3840,1)
    model = Sequential()
    #C1
    model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), strides=( 2, 2), padding='same',activation='relu', 
    input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=( 2, 2),  padding='same'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.compile(loss=categorical_focal_loss(), optimizer=opt_adam, metrics=['accuracy'])
    history=model.fit_generator(generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, train_data, start=0,end=100), 
                                validation_data=generate_arrays_for_training(indexPat, test_data, start=0,end=100),
                                steps_per_epoch=int((len(train_data)/2)), 
                                validation_steps=int((len(test_data)/2)),
                                verbose=2,epochs=65, max_queue_size=2, shuffle=True)
```

I want to make SVM classifier as my final classifier in this model so how can I do that?

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.